# How to pass a docopt argument where the argument is a string with spaces in python

Tags: python, bash, shell, command-line-arguments, docopt

How do I crate a docopt in python where my argument needs to be a string with spaces. I tried putting single and double quotes around it but it doesn't work.

This is my docopt string so far.

```
"""
Parser 
Usage: parser.py <trey_file> <als_cmd>

"""
```

> > parser.py myfile.py "This is an Orange" #doesn't work

Comment: What exactly happens, that exact doc string and test gives me `{'<als_cmd>': 'This is an Orange', '<trey_file>': 'myfile.py'}`.

Comment: that is a surprise. I tried the same thing on my python script and as well as the docopt site it didn't work at all: http://try.docopt.org/?doc=%22%22%22%0D%0AParser+%0D%0AUsage%3A+parser.py+%3Ctrey_file%3E+%3Cals_cmd%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%22%22%22&argv=myfile.py+%22This+is+orange%22

Comment: Yes, you were right. I tried it on my python script and now it seems to work. Looks like there is a bug in docopt site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docopt does not parse an argument string into an argument vector. Try the following.

```
"""
Parser
Usage: parser.py <trey_file> <als_cmd>

"""
print docopt(__doc__)
print docopt(__doc__, 'myfile.py "This is an Orange"')
print docopt(__doc__, ['myfile.py', 'This is an Orange'])
```

Run the script from your shell using `python parser.py myfile.py "This is an Orange"`.
The first case should work as expected because the shell splits the arguments into `sys.argv` as you expect. The second case fails with your problem because docopt expects its input already tokenized. The third case will work as expected.

As an aside, it seems that [try.docopt.org](https://github.com/docopt/try.docopt.org/blob/master/app.py#L33) makes the same mistake of passing a string instead of a vector to `docopt()`.

Comment: You are right @kalhartt. try.docopt.org is fooling me around. It works fine in my python interpreter!